# DAL generator for php

Tags: php, .net, data-access-layer, datamodel

Going from .Net to PHP because I want to explore the possibilities of the language I'm struggling to find some way to autogenerate a DAL. In .Net I'd just use visual studio to generate a datamodel, but how can I do that with PHP and MySQL, so I won't have to hand-type in all the classes? My current PHP IDE is Aptana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to jump into the idea behind PHP, and not just write .net style code in PHP, you need to move away from the Objects-all-over methods of .net.

As you've noticed, auto-generation of objects isn't common in PHP. Which means that the solution to the problem should not rely on this.

Try creating more generic objects and taking advantage of inheritance to avoid object bloat. And more-over try to rely less on data transfer objects and more on creating complete object-as-tool objects.

You'll find PHP to be much more of a joy to work with if you escape from the trappings of .net.

To put that in perspective, I don't think in the 5 years I have done work in PHP professionally, on big-scale projects like army.mil, have I ever felt the need to create a full-on DAL to get the job done.

The biggest project I've worked on just has a system of model classes each of which carry a list of methods that poll the database for raw data and then pass that data into the final objects. (in this case articles that make up the articles on army.mil)

There simply isn't a need for another layer between the model and the data in PHP. It almost always just means more work for no gain.

There are various reasons why they DO make sense in .net. Not the least of which being that they can be auto-generated trivially and therefore there is almost no time cost in having them.

That said, when encapsulated within the confines of a framework, DAL begins to make sense again. If your project is basic, I would suggest a framework like CodeIgniter. CI contains a really nice database abstraction system. It forgoes SQL in favor of methods that transform into whatever the particular database you've define in the configuration need. This serves the same purpose as a DAL. You are still creating the query in the model, and you still need to be aware of the structure of your database. But despite what .net want's you to believe, those are really still concerns for .net DALs anyway.

However, to really GET what PHP is all about, you need to lose the trappings of a framework and work freely. PHP is a hacker language. It affords hacking. (as in seat-of-your-pants programming, not cracking, ok, both..) And that is really what you need to do to understand what the fuss is about.

Is it a double-edged sword? Totally. But playing fast-and-loose with code is where PHP comes into its own. There is a reason it is the goto language for speedy up-over-night startups.

Sorry for the long and technically off-topic answer. I hope you can forgive me. You said you have started to use PHP to understand the possibilities of it. If you keep going this way - you'll decide it is weak, inaccurate, clumsy, and prone to errors; and you'll miss all the greatness that it offers in its flexibility, extensibility, hack-ability, and spirit. I don't want you to miss the point of the language.

Comment: thank you for this - I really appreciate posts like that. The reason I'm asking for at DAL is because I'm creating a REST service in PHP, and I wanted to go with what I thought was best practice, to avoid sql injections and stuff other security issues that I as a PHP noob may create, obviously influated by my .net thinking - I would love for you to comment on my project, perhaps I should create a seperate thread for this.

Comment: Might be helpful. But if what you are worried about is security, try using the mysqli interface in PHP and ensure you bind the parameters and that you do due-diligence as far as ensuring the data is correct. You won't need to run any mysql-based string escapers, as doing so along with the mysqli's parameter binding can result in double-escaping attack vectors.

Comment: Other .net to PHP security gotchas: weakly typed variables can lead to strange type-shifting behavior. Try type hinting in methods/functions and/or turning things into strings and parsing them very strictly (expensive resource wise, but the easiest of 'sure ways' to ensure integrity) -- Also, don't forget to run htmlentities() on any data from the user or database that you are about to output to the browser. This prevents XSS.

Comment: thanks :) I've looked a bit into codeigniter www.netuts.com has a really great tutorial series on this http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-1/

have I understood it correctly if I think that I can actually use the MVC pattern RESTfully?

Comment: Yes, you can. If you look at my.army.mil (which I built) you'll see a hybrid between CI's native url-segmentation system, and standard query strings. (which is the basis of REST) You can also tell CI to always use traditional query strings, although every link ends up looking like a google search URL. (which would be fine for a REST API)

Answer (score 3):

You could use an ORM like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [Propel](http://www.propelorm.org/).

These feature autogeneration of classes from schema, and vice versa.

If you need to write your own access layer, I would reccomend using [PHP Data Objects (PDO)](http://php.net/pdo) as it provides a nice OO interface, and DB engine abstraction.

Answer (score 2):

Normally I wouldn't write an answer, since you have 2 already, but I'd like to give you some insights of my own, giving the fact that Im a .NET and PHP developer and try to take advantge of both:

- If you are looking for code generation powerful as Visual Studio, then look no more because in PHP I haven't found one yet and I've been looking for years. Visual Studio is just "**huge**"
- To my understanding there is not such thing as .NET code style. I believe that most PHP frameworks / applications sacrifice much in the sake of "simplicity" and I think is just not right. Code should be extensible, maintainable and scalable in any framework/application you buid
- Propel and Doctrine are outstanding for data mapping (ORM), much as NHibernate or Entity Framework in PHP, but remeber that you'll need a Data Access Layer and a Business Access Layer for a fully developed application to be scalable.
- Keep in mind that PHP supports OO much like .NET, but differs in a few things, but well develop designs are meant for ANY language.

I think my answer has gone a bit away from the original question, but I liked to give you a bigger answer, since like you said, you wanted to:

> ...explore the possibilities of the
>   language...

And you need many opinions to form your own. Best of luck in you endevours and hope that my answer hasn't killed you of boredom! :)

PS: Should you like some more stuff on BLL and DAL using PHP, check out [this article](http://davidcondemarin.blogspot.com/2010/11/using-orm-classes-as-business-models.html) I wrote in my blog.

Comment: I appreciate your input very much - nice article, I hope you'll be writing more blogposts.

Comment: Thank you for taking some time to read it. Im kinda bussy now with writing a book on web development on PHP, but I have a few drafts already. Best regards